# How to write a python function for csv writer

Tags: python, csv

I have the following code that works fine:

```
with open('userWithAgentProp.csv','w+') as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f,user_keys)
        w.writeheader()
        for user in userAgentProp_list:
            w.writerow(user)
```

I used this code to write a function:

```
def createCSVOutput(fileName, keys, listOfLists):
    with open(fileName, 'w+') as f:
        w= csv.dictWriter(f, keys)
        w.writeheader()
        for row in listOfLists:
            w.writerow(row)
```

When I call the function:

```
createCSVOutput('new_test_csv.csv', user_keys, userAgentProp_list)
```

I get the following error:

```
File "mongodb_script_2.py", line 101, in <module>
  createCSVOutput('new_test_csv.csv', user_keys, userAgentProp_list)
File "mongodb_script_2.py", line 54, in createCSVOutput
  w= csv.dictWriter(f, keys)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dictWriter'
```

Why does it work for `user_keys` variable in the script, but not in the function?

Comment: You probably have something shadowing the `csv` name. Consider posting more code (or just look for what could be causing it).

Comment: I assume you do realize that you didn't capitalize the D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:

`csv.dictWriter` is wrong. It should be `csv.DictWriter`.

Comment: everybody can do such as mistake.